# Failed Backup Job With Backup Exec 12 and AOFO

Tags: backup

I am backing up a Windows 2003 Small Business Server with SP2. We are running Backup Exec 12 with SP4. Recently the backup job started failing on backing up the system state with the following error:

> V-79-57344-34110 - AOFO:
>   Initialization failure on:
>   "System?State". Advanced Open File
>   Option used: Microsoft Volume Shadow
>   Copy Service (VSS). Snapshot provider
>   error (0xE000FE7D): Access is denied.
>   To back up or restore System State,
>   administrator privileges are required.
>   Check the Windows Event Viewer for
>   details.

Upon review of Symantec's website the error indicates a credential problem. However when I test the credentials they come back with no failures. I have found another forum [here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/failed-backups-hotfix) referencing a similar error and have tried what has been indicated with no succesful results. I have created new jobs based on new selection lists with no succesful results.

I suspect a new update possibly from Microsoft may be causing this but I have no idea which one. I am looking for feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue finally. Symantec changed something is SP4 for BackupExec 12 that requires that you predicate the service account being used for backups to include the domain (i.e. domainname\service account). Changed to this topology and backups function properly